# how to print response from an api in php separately

Tags: php, arrays, api, printing, response

i am able to print the response from an api but it is nested array i am not able to save it.

```
    Array
 (
   [statuscode] => 0
   [status] => SUCCESS
   [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
      (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (

                        [BENEID] => 227287
                        [BENENAME] => test
                        [BANKNAME] => test
                        [BRANCHNAME] => test
                        [CITY] => test
                        [STATE] => tetst
                        [IFSCCODE] => HBNB
                        [ACCOUNTNO] => 4545345
                        [MMID] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                       (
                                [0] =>  
                        )

                        [MOBILE] => 0
                        [BENESTATUS] => Approved
                        [MMIDSTATUS] => 0
                        [IFSCSTATUS] => 1
                        [IMPSMMIDENABLE] => 0
                        [IMPSIFSCENABLE] => 0
                        [IMPSNEFTENABLE] => 1
                        [DELETESTATUS] => 0
                    )
                  )
               )
           )
```

This is the response i am getting i want to print all fields separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very simple just follow the structure of response which you are getting from API

Try this:-

I suppose your repsonse in a array **$reponseArray**

```
foreach($reponseArray['item']->item as $value)
{
  foreach($value as $key=>$val)
  {
    echo $key.' = '. $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you it was great help is there any way in i can print only selected data not all the data.

Comment: yes of course you can print. but got that you need to know exact array index and object key.